# angular-ui-router only loads template but not controller not loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to migrate my Angular app from using ngRoute to uiRoute. Everything works fine except the controllers. They simple don't load like they did with ngRoute and I don't get why. As I see it from uiRoute it should work like with ngRoute but it doesn't. There is no exception thrown. I also don't find any example for a similar configuration like mine although it's very simple. I home somebody can tell me where my controller is hiding.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VGyi3AxgslgpvwBCTkXI?p=preview

So as for ngRoute the controller should be accessible through 'homepage' but it looks like it's just empty :(

```
;(function(angular) {
'use strict';

 angular
 .module('MainRouter', ['ui.router'])
 .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '',
      views: {
        "mainView": {
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }
      },
      controller: 'HomepageCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'homepage'
    });
 }]);
})(angular);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `views` option inside the state definition, then `ui-router` engine doesn't look for `templateUrl` & `controller` defined in state level, basically you need to provide `controller` & `templateUrl` value from the `namedView` definition only. In your case you should add controller in `mainView` definition object.

**Code**

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '',
      views: {
        "mainView": {
          templateUrl: 'home.html',
          controller: 'HomepageCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'homepage'
        }
      },
    });
}]);
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WOzmFmsyBiPNupgtbvMM?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I somehow was convinced, that controllers are global for very state. But I guess that's just how I would do it :D

Comment: @DaSch Glad to help you.Thanks :)